# Date, find out the number of days in a month

Tags: linux, date

How can I use the **date** command to find out the number of days in the current and next month?

Comment: Why does this need to be done in `date`? Except for leap years the number of days in each month is fixed.

Comment: I haven't found any other utilities, but did find mention that this date can do it. If you can suggest another way that doesn't force me to install something on the system, and the structures for these operations will be small.

Comment: My question is: why does this need *any* utility to do it for you? This is a [trivial lookup against month numbers](https://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/months/) with a [check for leap years](https://www.wikihow.com/Calculate-Leap-Years): `jan=31, if (leap year) then (feb = 29) else (feb = 28), mar = 31, apr = 30 .... etc `

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? Why do you believe that `date` is the correct tool for this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brute force: generate the next 31 & 62 days and take the biggest number:

```
month=$(date +%m)
maxDayThisMonth=$(( for d in {00..31}; do date -d "+$d days" +%m-%d ; done ; ) | grep -Po "(?<=$month-)\d+" | sort -rn | head -1)

nextMonth=$(printf "%02d" $(( ($month+1) % 12 )) )
maxDayNextMonth=$(( for d in {01..62}; do date -d "+$d days" +%m-%d ; done ; ) | grep -Po "(?<=$nextMonth-)\d+" | sort -rn | head -1)
```

`grep -P` is a GNU-ism but since this is for Linux... Otherwise you can replace by a more conventional `grep`+`cut`.

Comment: It seems to work, thanks a lot. But I don't quite understand how it works?

Comment: The `for` loop generates all MM-DD for the next 31 days (10-30,10-31, 11-01,11-02...), `grep` keeps those of the current month  (30, 31) (there is a "lookbehind" to keep only those after `10-`), and then they are reverse ordered and the first is kept. Same for next month  but the sequence is longer and can have days from three months.

Comment: Gotta love the modern computer paradigm of brute force and ignorance to run a program 62 times, fumble blindly through the output and then strip out what you don't want. Disk costs are basically zero due to caches and such, but running date to get the current month number (and therefore next month number as well) and then doing a simple lookup has to be more computationally efficient and elegant? Sure this gets you the task done in four lines instead of a big case statement, but that can't be the metric for "best" when you have to spend so much time tying it all together in the first place.

Comment: @Mokubai Plain fun. On a more philosophical level, this also let me rely on the authors of `date` for actual leap years and such (the only "side knowledge" I use in the solution above is that there are 12 months in a year)(scars of Y2K battles:)), and if the code had to do it very many times it would do a lookup... but using a table generated with `date` :)